# using action bar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i'm pretty confused on how to use action bar sherlock.. i've 'installed' it successfully in my apps (I can already see the bar at the top of my apps), but how do I 'configure' it? for example i use this

```
<item name="abDisplayOptions">useLogo|showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
```

so I can see the apps logo in the action bar, the 'back' button at the left side of the logo, but I don't know where should I put the code (and what code to write) to enable the 'back' buttons on action bar, clicking on logo will bring the user to the apps home, and other things such as put a search icon on the action bar and so on.. i tried looking at the actionbarsherlock google groups but I don't know what to search to help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the samples here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos

And the corresponding code here : https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: The first URL is the actual app. You can download it from the Market and play with it on your device. Then you'll see what ABS can do for you. If you want the same functionality as a particulair example, then go to the source code with the corresponding name. Here comes the second URL, just download the ZIP from that website and go to the classes with the code : https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/app You will see the simple and effective sample code here.